# Why `ccmake` is having a different `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` than my `cmake`?

Tags: cmake

I use `cmake` to generate my makefile and then I want to check the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` with `ccmake .`, I don't understand why `ccmake .` is still showing the default `/usr/local` as my `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?

The `MESSAGE` output and `make install` both indicate that I have set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` correctly, I am just wondering why `ccmake` is giving a wrong info? Any ideas?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7 FATAL_ERROR)

PROJECT(ddd)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/bin")
MESSAGE ("CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
add_executable(ddd MACOSX_BUNDLE ddd.CPP)
set_property(TARGET ddd PROPERTY INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
INSTALL(TARGETS ddd DESTINATION .)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values displayed by `ccmake` are the ones from the CMake cache, which is stored in `CMakeCache.txt`. The values displayed by your message call are that of a local variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` that you set one line before and which hides the cached value of the same name.

If you want to change the cached value instead, use a forced [set](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aset) instead:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/bin" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
```

Note that in general it is not a good idea to change those values from inside your CMakeLists, as it will invalidate any attempts of the user to change the default configuration. In this particular case of changing `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` you are also likely to break the build on Windows platforms.

Comment: Are you saying that if (for example on windows), if there is no "/home/bin" such path, it will be installed to the default windows' path stored in the "CACHE PATH"?

Comment: @Daniel I'd say it's more likely it will refuse to install at all and quit with a potentially horribly confusing error message instead.

Comment: Okay, I see, I will not touch the `CACHE PATH`. Thank you very much.

Comment: CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is treated differently than most other variables.  There's another variable CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT that will be set if -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is not specified.  However, that's for any cmake call.  ie, if you update a CMakeLists.txt and run make, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_SET_TO_DEFAULT will be set so you need to be very careful when deal with CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.